# How to clear/empty list before another list been added?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an assignment that requires me to creating a contact App by storing data in any data structure not in ant text file or db. I choose to use an arraylist to for my data.

App consists of a few different features, such as creating a contact, view, delete, search and update by entering fields like name, phone number (more than 1 can exist for a single contact),email id(0 or more can exist for a single contact), address, and  Date of Birth. For storing phone number and email id I chose to create a separate lists for both and store them in main the arraylist along with other fields.

But the problem I am facing is that once i create a contact with all the fields entered and created one more contact at the same time with all fields filled, then try to view the created contacts, both contacts end up having the same phone numbers and email id, which i entered separately for each. how do I avoid/clear the list once it has been added and before another list empty?

I am also wondering how i can update a phone number and email id already stored in the main list?

I am really new to java. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
contList.add(new Contact(name,phoneNumberList,emailidList,addrs,dob,group)); 
System.out.println("Contact has been created");
//phoneNumberList.clear(); // its printing as this with no elements conPhNo=[]
// emailidList.clear(); // conEmail=[]
```

Comment: please post your sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create contactBean and then store or retrieve data using setter/getters. Then create arrayList typed to contactBean and add contactBean to the list. If you want to update use primary key like contact id or some attribute of contact that you decide which is unique to each contact. Answering you question, how to clear arrayList.

```
ArrayList<ContactBean> contactList=new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
//some code here
contactList.clear();
```